# Alternatives to __syncthreads() in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am working on parallelizing a C code using CUDA. What I have figured out is that we can do our computations in the following pattern :
[image: computational pattern]

Therefore, we can compute only one element labelled '1' in first step, only after the first element's computation is done we can start computing the next two diagonal elements labelled '2', as we have data dependency. So on and so forth for other elements ...

The approach that we have taken to solve this problem is to assign a thread to each row, where each one of them execute `__syncthreads()` at the end of each step to achieve the aforementioned synchronization.

But, `__syncthreads()` takes a lot of time. Is there any alternate solution to this issue.

**EDIT 1:**
The dependency pattern for computing each element `X` is as follows :

[image: 5 point stencil]

here, element `X` requires the values of red and green coloured elements.
It is dependent only on the elements coloured red (which are computed in the previous iteration).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific about dependency pattern? Does every element on `n`th step depends on every element on step `n-1` or there is some kind of locality?

Comment: @SteelRaven I have edited my question. Yeah! there is some kind of locality.

Comment: @AnastasiyaAsadullayeva The computation of each element `X` in this matrix follows the structure, as shown in EDIT 1. This computation happens row by row in the sequential version. I thought the above parallel diagonal structure best addresses this computation pattern. But, I am not happy with the side effects of `__syncthreads()`.

Comment: This is a solved problem (google "A FAST ITERATIVE METHOD FOR EIKONAL EQUATIONS" by Whitaker and Jeong)

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit the fact that all threads in warp are executed simultaneously and do not need to be explicitly synchronized. To do so let's make every warp to evaluate an independent big chunk of result and use synchronization only between big chuncks processing. Let's load boundary data for big square chunks and process them within independent warps.
[image]
Here I tried to draw the new pattern, every square surrounds single warp's data, color switch denotes need to synchronize, `L` means that warp need to load that element, `E` means that warp will be responsible for element evaluation. Of course chunks must be as big as warp, not as small as on image.

Code might look like this:

```
volatile shared sharedChunks[warpsInBlock][33][33];
int warpId = threadIdx.x / 32;
int inWarpId = threadIdx.x % 32;
while(not done){
  sharedChunks[warpId][0][inWarpId + 1] =
    data[mapToCorrectHorisontalLoadId(threadIdx, iteration)];
  sharedChunks[warpId][inWarpId + 1][0] =
    data[mapToCorrectVerticalLoadId(threadIdx, iteration)];
  // Filling upper left triangle of array
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
    if(inWarpId <= i){
      sharedChunks[warpId][i - inWarpId + 1][inWarpId + 1] =
        sharedChunks[warpId][i - inWarpId][inWarpId + 1] +
        sharedChunks[warpId][i - inWarpId + 1][inWarpId];
    }
  }
  // Filling lower right triangle of array
  for(int i = 1; i < 32; ++i){
    if(inWarpId >= i)
      sharedChunks[warpId][i + inWarpId + 1][31 - inWarpId + 1] =
        sharedChunks[warpId][i + inWarpId][31 - inWarpId + 1] +
        sharedChunks[warpId][i + inWarpId + 1][31 - inWarpId];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
    data[backwardMapping(threadIdx, iteration, i)] =
      sharedChunks[warpId][i + 1][inWarpId + 1];
  }
  __syncthreads();
}
```

Here to fully evaluate elements on 32 diagonals you will need to make only two synchronizations instead of 32.

But this solution has its own downsides:

1. You must figure out the mapping from your global memory data indices to intrawarp indices. If loads or stores won't be coalesced enough you might not get any speedup.
2. As you can see some of threads are doing nothing for lots of time during chunk evaluation. Roughly half of time won't be used.
3. Highly dependent on shared memory available for block. Shared memory usage can be lowered in cost of more synchronizations. For example you can use array of size `(warpsInBlock*2)x17x17`, here every warp will be evaluating two smaller chunks and shared memory usage will be roughly twice lower, but synchronizations number will be twice higher.

Maybe anything else what I forgot.

You might try to do it this way but real speedup will be highly dependent on many factors.

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly, sorry to resurrect a super old thread.*

You could reorder the items (through clever addressing, not in memory) to get an access pattern like:

```
1
2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4  4
```

... and so on. You'd need a `__syncthreads()` only after each such row, which would be much faster.